# insert data from android to server

Tags: php, android, insert

I want to save data into a server. This is my simple php code:

```
<?php
require('Zend\Db.php');
require('Zend\Db\Exception.php');
function sendResponse($status, $payload)
{
$responseCodeList = array(
    200 => 'OK',
    201 => 'Created',
    204 => 'No Content',
    301 => 'Moved Permanently',
    400 => 'Bad Request',
    404 => 'Not Found',
    410 => 'Gone',
    501 => 'Not Implemented',
);

header('HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . $responseCodeList[$status]);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo (string) $payload;
}
try {

$db = Zend_Db::factory('Oracle', array(
    'host'       => '10.234.152.6',
    'username'   => 'DMHR',
    'password'   => '',
    'dbname'     => '//10.234.152.6/SATHRIS',
));
} catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
echo sendResponse(200,'100|Database Error');
exit;
}

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$payload = '';

if ($method = 'GET') {
   $data = $_GET;
try {
     $array_data = array(
        'AD_KODE_TOKO' => $data['kode_toko'],
        'AD_NAMA' => $data['nama'];
        'AD_ALAMAT' => $data['alamat'],
        'AD_KODE_POS' => $data['kode_pos'],
        'AD_NO_TELP' => $data['no_telp'],
        'AD_LONGITUDE' => $data['longitude'],
        'AD_LATITUDE' => $data['latitude'],
        'AD_PERUSAHAAN' => $data['perusahaan'],
    );

    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->insert('ANDROID_DATA', $array_data);
    $db->commit();
    $payload = 'SUCCESS';
} catch(Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
    $payload = 'FAILURE';
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    echo "</pre>";
}

}

echo sendResponse(200, $payload);
```

...and this is my main Activity to save into the server:

```
private EditText etkdstore;
private EditText etnama;
private EditText etalamat;
private EditText etkdpos;
private EditText etnotelp;
private EditText etlng;
private EditText etlat;
private EditText etperush;
//private TextView idgambar;

private Button save;

private String url = "10.234.152.6/upload_get.php";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    etkdstore = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kdstore);
    etnama = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nama);
    etalamat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.alamat);
    etkdpos = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kdpos);
    etnotelp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.telp);
    etlng = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lng);
    etlat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lat);
    etperush = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.perush);
   // idgambar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gambar);

    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
    // setiap parameter yang akan dikirim melalui http
    // harus encode agar
    // dapat terbaca dengan baik oleh server
    String kdstore = URLEncoder.encode(etkdstore.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    String nama = URLEncoder.encode(etnama.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    String alamat = URLEncoder.encode(etalamat.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    String kdpos = URLEncoder.encode(etkdpos.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    String notelp = URLEncoder.encode(etnotelp.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    String lng = URLEncoder.encode(etlng.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    String lat = URLEncoder.encode(etlat.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    String perush = URLEncoder.encode(etperush.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    //String gambar = URLEncoder.encode(idgambar.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
    url += "?kode_toko=" + kdstore + "&&nama" + nama + "&&alamat=" + alamat + "&&kode_pos=" + kdpos +
    "&&no_telp=" + notelp + "&&longitude=" + lng + "&&latitude=" + lat + "&&perusahaan=" + perush;
    getRequest(url);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });
}
public void getRequest(String Url) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data " + Url + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data " + request(response) + " ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data Gagal !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
public static String request(HttpResponse response) {

            String result = "";
            try {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
                in.close();
                result = str.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                result = "Error";
            }

            return result;
        }
```

In my case, I want to save data to the server, but I can't save data into the server. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this example.I think it may help to you

```
         JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
         try {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mernalaw.com/financeassessment.php");
             json.put("Income","1 - $30,000"); 
             json.put("Household","1");  

             json.put("Employment","Employed"); 
             json.put("RealEstate","Primary residence"); 
             json.put("Vehicle","No"); 
             json.put("Name","vvk"); 
             json.put("Email","vvkrishna1989@gmail.com"); 
             json.put("CellPhone","99999999999"); 
             json.put("City","hyd"); 

             Log.i("jason Object", json.toString()); 
             httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString()); 

             StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
             se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8"); 
             se.setContentType("application/json"); 
             httppost.setEntity(se);              
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
             int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(statusCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             is = se.getContent();
             Log.e("log_tag", "connection success "+"status code"+statusCode);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: now i want upload file from sdcard into directory on web server..how to upload into directory on web server??thank you

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272518/upload-imageview-to-server/9272639#9272639

Comment: when i run in emulator it is work.but if i try in device can't work result is time out..:(

Comment: check internet connection.If your internetr is slow you will get timeout error

Comment: i think in url problem..my url not open and it is in local server..:(

Comment: @VenkataKrishna:Actually I am totally new for this server concept and i need your help.Should I ask some ques to u?